# loop update part of slice in Ruby

Tags: ruby

On the sample trying to update specific range of slice.

```
#sample
arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
arr[0...3] = [1,1,1]
#=> [1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

When i loop it, something weird is happening. What exactly am i missing here ?

```
matrix = Array.new(4, Array.new(7, 0))
1.downto(0){|x| matrix[x][0...3] = [3,3,3]}
#=> [[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 

#expecting
#[[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Where did you think that 1's would come from?  You don't use `arr` anywhere in the second block of code.

Comment: UPDATED: 1's is just sample. When i loop it, it updates entire arrays in the matrix. But supposed to update only based on index range of `{|x|}`

Comment: Your array constructor looks broken. That creates a 4-element array where all the elements are the *same object*.

Comment: When you label something as "expecting", that means you are, you know, *expecting* that.

Comment: Don't use the ellipsis version of range (`...`), use the standard version (`..`). The first works but it also is harder to spot when debugging, and is the source of errors. `(1...2).to_a   #=> [1]` vs. `(1..2).to_a   #=> [1, 2]`. See the Ruby style guides.

Comment: @theTinMan in my case i had to `[0..d[1]-1]` or `[0...d[1]]`, i just used 3 dots `...`. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic mistake where the array is actually multiple instances of the same object. Remember that arguments are evaluated once and once only, so:

```
matrix = Array.new(4, Array.new(7, 0))
```

Produces an array where all 4 elements are the same object.

Imagine you'd done this instead:

```
element = Array.new(7, 0)
matrix = Array.new(4, element)
```

That would make it pretty clear they're all the same element. Think of this as the "expanded" version of the original code.

You need to switch to the block constructor:

```
matrix = Array.new(4) { Array.new(7, 0) }
```

Where that works now. Each element is the result of *evaluating the block*, so you get different objects each time.

In the second case `0` is just a number and while technically an object, since you can't modify it, the difference is purely academic.

Your original code works up until the point where you modify the arrays.

Comment: From my sample: i was expecting this by shotway `element = Array.new(7, 0); matrix = Array.new(4, element)`, i didnt know it takes block constructor for that.

Comment: A lot of Ruby methods take either arguments and/or blocks as sometimes the block is the best way to express the desired outcome. An argument is evaluated once, a block *zero or more times*.

Answer (score 2):

`matrix` is an array of four elements, all of which are the *same* list. That's because the `Array.new(7, 0)` part gets evaluated once, and a reference to it gets placed at four places in the outer array. Fortunately, [`Array::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-c-new) provides a form that takes a block to get around exactly this issue.

```
matrix = Array.new(4) { Array.new(7, 0) }
```

Now, the thing inside the block is evaluates separately each time, giving you an array of four actually distinct arrays.

Generally, use this block form if you're planning to mutate the things on the inside. If the things on the inside are immutable (esp. if they're numbers or some datatype like that that's immutable by nature), then the sharing of data is fine and can actually save you some space.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now.